# Is there a faster way to lookup dictionary indices?

Tags: python, dictionary, nlp

I am trying to look up dictionary indices for thousands of strings and this process is very, very slow. There are package alternatives, like `KeyedVectors` from `gensim.models`, which does what I want to do in about a minute, but I want to do what the package does more manually and to have more control over what I am doing.

I have two objects: (1) a dictionary that contains key : values for word embeddings, and (2) my pandas dataframe with my strings that need to be transformed into the index value found for each word in object (1). Consider the code below -- is there any obvious improvement to speed or am I relegated to external packages?

I would have thought that key lookups in a dictionary would be blazing fast.

## Object 1

```
embeddings_dictionary = dict()
glove_file = open('glove.6B.200d.txt', encoding="utf8")
for line in glove_file:
    records = line.split()
    word = records[0]
    vector_dimensions = np.asarray(records[1:], dtype='float32')
    embeddings_dictionary [word] = vector_dimensions
```

## Object 2 (The slowdown)

```
no_matches = []
glove_tokenized_data = []
for doc in df['body'][:5]:
    doc = doc.split()
    ints = []
    for word in doc:
        try:
    # the line below is the problem
            idx = list(embeddings_dictionary.keys()).index(word)
        except:
            idx = 400000  # unknown
            no_matches.append(word)
        ints.append(idx)
    glove_tokenized_data.append(ints)
```

Comment: why do you convert it to a list every time inside the loop, instead you can have the list permanently created outside the loop. list(embeddings_dictionary.keys()).index(word) this line..

Comment: I don't understand what the np array is for or what the index is. Its not an index into `embeddings_dictionary`. Since python dicts now preserve insertion order, it would be the order in which the words were read, but I'm not sure what the usefulness is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got a mapping of word -> np.array. It appears you want a quick way to map word to its location in the key list. You can do that with another dict.

```
no_matches = []
glove_tokenized_data = []
word_to_index = dict(zip(embeddings_dictionary.keys(), range(len(embeddings_dictionary))))
for doc in df['body'][:5]:
    doc = doc.split()
    ints = []
    for word in doc:
        try:
            idx = word_to_index[word]
        except KeyError:
            idx = 400000  # unknown
            no_matches.append(word)
        ints.append(idx)
    glove_tokenized_data.append(ints)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help -- this solves the look up VERY quickly

Answer (score 1):

In the line you marked as a problem, you are first creating a list from the keys and then looking up the word in the list. You're doing this inside the loop so the first thing you could do is take this logic to the top of the block (outside the loop) to avoid repeated processing and second you're doing all this searching now on a list, not a dictionary.

Why not create another dictionary like this on top of the file:

```
reverse_lookup = { word: index for word, index in enumerate(embeddings_dictionary.keys()) }
```

and then use this dictionary to look up the index of your word. Something like this:

```
for word in doc:
   if word in reverse_lookup:
       ints.append(reverse_lookup[word])
   else:
       no_matches.append(word)
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and intuition -- I think this will solve it but is not immediately working; the below is very similar idea and is working out of the box.